# Sharing variables in OOP AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, scope, encapsulation

In Main.as I have the following:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        public var damage:Number;

        public function Main() {
            // constructor code

            var char:Character = new Character();
            addChild(char);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have another package called Character.as

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip; 

    public class Character extends MovieClip{

        public function Character() {
            trace(damage);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to be able to share the damage set in the main.as with the character. Is there any way to make the speed more global?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you make damage a public property of your Character and then it'll be easily accessible via your Main class like this :

```
char.damage = 100;
trace (char.damage);
```

To do this, just add the property to your Character class like so :

```
public class Character extends MovieClip {

    public var damage:Number;

    public function Character() {
        trace(damage);
    }
}
```

But given your comment, I take it you would rather everything just be global and accessible everywhere as opposed to applying OOP concepts.

If so... just define it as a public static in your Main class like this :

```
public static var damage:Number;
```

and to access it anywhere you do this :

```
Main.damage = 100; 
trace(Main.damage);
```

Comment: Your approach is therefore not very OOP. Make it a public static variable.

Comment: updated my answer. If you are looking to utilize OOP, you should take a step back and learn some of the basic OOP design concepts / patterns.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I guess I need to learn a but more about oop before trying something like this. Thanks.

Comment: I do think it's more efficient to first learn about OOP. Starting with a book/tutorial on OOP would speed you up greatly. I made that transition and it cleared so many questions I was having up, quickly and efficiently. It doesn't seem like it's faster and I'm sure we all like to just jump right in. But, to be honest, the quickest route is getting that basic understanding first. You won't waste hours wondering why you don't get it and trying to do simple things.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of sending values through packages (This way is not really sharing variables, but it could be useful for you). What this code does is that the class Character creates a variable, and this variables gets an value from the Main package:

Change the character.as to this:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip; 

public class Character extends MovieClip{

    public function Character(a:int) {
      //output will be the integer 10   
              trace(a);
    }
}
}
```

and main.as to:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Main extends MovieClip {

    private var damage:int = 10;

    private var char:Character = new Character(damage);

    public function Main() {

    }
}
}
```

- Edit: Not useful for realtime applications, because the values of `private var damage` will only be send on initialization of `private var char:Character = new Character(damage)`.

Comment: This would not work as you are creating a 'new' instance of the Main class within his character class, which I am assuming is his document class.

Comment: You were right. Declaring a private var _main:Main = New Main() in the Charater package didn't work. I updated it now.

Comment: Your current code will allow him to pass damage value to the constructor when creating the `Character` instance. What about when he wants to utilize damage AFTER the instance is created ? After the constructor completes, `a` no longer exists as it's a parameter and doesn't get stored in a property in your constructor. Also keep in mind that primitive types are passed as values not references. So even if you stored that value in a property, if damage changed after the instance was created, the `Character` instance would only have the initial value of damage that was passed to the constructor.

Comment: True story. This way of sending values to another package is not usefull for real time computing.